# Show Only Month Picker in MaterialDateTimePicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm using this [link](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) for date picker, I want to show only Month in date picker. How can i achieve this?

and also know

- how to show Only Year Picker.

Comment: please check your link... its not working

Comment: https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker - Please check this

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following lib: https://github.com/lutvie72/RackMonthPicker.

[image]

```
 new RackMonthPicker(this)
     .setPositiveButton(new DateMonthDialogListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDateMonth(int month, int startDate, int endDate, int year, String monthLabel) {

           }
      })
      .setNegativeButton(new OnCancelMonthDialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(AlertDialog dialog) {

            }
      }).show();
```

Comment: The most critical issue with this library is that it shows hardcoded 2017 year by default.

Comment: Although the author has fixed it, but its still not released. You can find the snapshot 1.5.1 with the issue fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best option I think : https://github.com/DogusTeknoloji/compose-date-picker

Year Picker:

[image]

Month Picker:

[image]

```
ComposeCalendar(  
  minDate: Date? = null,  // Set min selectable date
  maxDate: Date? = null,  // Set max selectable date
  locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault(),  // Set locale for localization
  title: String = "",  // Set title 
  listener: SelectDateListener, // Set Listener for selected date
  showOnlyMonth: Boolean = false,  // Display only month picker
  showOnlyYear: Boolean = false,  // Display only year picker
  themeColor:Color = Color(0xFF614FF0), // Set picker color 
  negativeButtonTitle:String = "CANCEL",  // Set negative button text
  positiveButtonTitle:String = "OK"  // Set positive button text
)
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way, maybe not te purest one is to extend `DatePickerDialog`
all you need it to override `onYearSelected` callback and then also `newInstance` because if you don't do that it will produce `DatePickerDialog`,  not new `YearOnlyPicker` object. Additionaly in `newInstance` I've added `showYearPickerFirst(true)` call but it can be done also from out side. Then you can use this dialog as original one. It's kind of hack but it's only way to achieve that without modifying library source code

here is class that extends DatePickerDialog

```
    import com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog;

    public class YearOnlyPicker extends DatePickerDialog {

        public static YearOnlyPicker newInstance(OnDateSetListener callBack, int year,
                                           int monthOfYear,
                                           int dayOfMonth) {
            YearOnlyPicker ret = new YearOnlyPicker();
            ret.showYearPickerFirst(true);
            ret.initialize(callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            return ret;
        }
        @Override
        public void onYearSelected(int year) {
            super.onYearSelected(year);
            notifyOnDateListener();
            dismiss();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi,What about for only month view

Comment: you mean spinner with only months names? there is no such view in MaterialDateTimePicker - you need to implement it by your own - you can base on Year View as it will work same but i think it will be easier to implement it from scratch as it is simple sppinner view

Comment: maybe this one will meet your needs : https://github.com/resengupta/Month-Year-Date-Picker